# Problem with FindRoot + NDSolve + InterpolatingFunctionDomain

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, numerical-value

I'm trying to find the root (po) of a complicated problem (where s is a parameter):

First, I need to define some functions, which involve numerically solving a differential equation.

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];

a[po_, s_] := NDSolve[{3*F[p] + p*F'[p] - 2*s*(3*F''[p] + p*F'''[p]) == 0, F[po] == 1, F'[po] == 0, 
F''[po] == (-1 + 3*po - 3*po^2 - 2*s)/(2*s*po*(1 - 2*po)), WhenEvent[F[p] == 0, "StopIntegration"]}, F, {p, 0.01}]

plownum[po_, s_] := InterpolatingFunctionDomain[First[F /. a[po, s]]][[1, 1]]

plowdensity[po_, s_] := First[F'[plownum[po, s]] /. a[po, s]]

plowprofit[po_, s_] := plownum[po, s]^2 (1 + 2 s*plowdensity[po, s])

rootpo[po_, s_] := plowprofit[po, s] - (po^2*(1 - 2*po + po^2 + 2*s))/(2 - 4*po)
```

Without explaining in detail what I'm trying to achieve, everything works perfectly up to that point (since I'm not extremely familiar with the intricacies of Mathematica, even that took me a while). The function rootpo[po,s] evaluates very quickly and without problems.

However, when trying to find the value of po where rootpo[po,s] == 0, I get a problem when using FindRoot:

```
poeq[s_] := FindRoot[rootpo[po, s], {po, 0.1}]

poeq[0.2]
```

leads to a large error output:

```
NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable F.
ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{...},F,{p,0.01}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```

etc.

I tried different things (including looking up solutions to similar problems and adjusting the code), but unfortunately I still couldn't get the FindRoot[.] to run.

Can anybody help me? I'm also happy about suggestions how to clean up the code.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want some [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) on the function arguments in the definitions, like `a[po_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := ...`.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that (changed the arguments in every function definition), but unfortunately I get the same error message.

Comment: you should update the question with that fix. Be sure to restart your kernel after making such change as well.

Comment: Also your `NDSolve` domain doesn't look right, perhaps should be `{p,po,upperlim}` where the upper limit is some sufficiently large number or `Infinity` presuming you want it to just go until `WhenEvent` stops it. ?

Comment: taking back the last comment, that seems to work, `NDSolve` evidently takes a limit from your initial condition, so you implicitly have `{p, 0.01, po}`. I cant see where that feature is documented though.

Comment: I didn't restart the kernel initially, and it seems that things do change quite a bit after the suggested modification. I will look into that tomorrow. Regarding your other comments: The NDSolve seems to work just fine, even though I might be lucky there. Thanks again!

Comment: Martin, I should've inserted a `ClearAll[a]` to wipe out the previous definition: `ClearAll[a]; a[po_?NumericQ,....`  Restarting the kernel clears all definitions, too, of course. -- @george2079 `{x, x1}` is [an old legacy form](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v2/contents/list433.pdf) that implies `{x, x0, x1}` where `x0` is taken from the IC (so `{p, po, 0.01}` implied in the OP's code).

Comment: Thanks a bunch - adding ?NumericQ to the function definitions did work indeed (after restarting the kernel). I thus consider the problem as solved...